# why array taking random value?

Tags: c++, arrays

I assign value in my array but it randomly taking diffrent values. why is this happening?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int n;
cin>>n;
int arr[n][n];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for (int j= 0; j < n; j++){
    cin>>arr[i][j];
    }
}
int sum,count= 0;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        arr[i-1][j]=0;
        arr[i][j-1]=0;
        arr[n+1][j]=0;
        arr[i][n+1]=0;

        cout<<arr[i][j+1]<<" "<<arr[i][j-1]<<" "<<arr[i+1][j]<<" "<<arr[i-1][j]<<"\n";
        //sum = arr[i][j+1]+arr[i][j-1]+arr[i+1][j]+arr[i-1][j];

        //cout<<sum<<" ";
    }
}
```

}

**Input**:
2
1 2
3 4

**Output**:
2 4218949 3 1878280832
3 1 0 4218949
0 0 1998471964 1
1998471964 3 0 0

Comment: Why you have -1 as array index?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing more code, but I imagine that `arr[-1][j]=0;
        arr[i][-1]=0;
        arr[n+1][j]=0;
        arr[i][n+1]=0;` is supposed to be this `arr[i-1][j]=0;
        arr[i][j-1]=0;
        arr[i+1][j]=0;
        arr[i][j+1]=0;`

Comment: @john then every value will be zero bro.

Comment: no actually i have to sum value to the top,left,right and bottom. so in case of i=0,j=0 arr[-1][0] will be 0 to the left there is no element so we consider it as 0 and same goes for the up direction @TigerYu

Comment: `to the left there is no element so we consider it as 0` you might consider it to be zero, but your compiler doesn't agree. You need to test for that case.

Comment: Anyway for anyone to correct the errors in your code you need to post a complete program. When we can't see how you declare the array, how you initialise the array and how you print out the values it's really impossible to say anything with any certainty.

Comment: @Evilport There is no straightforward declaration of an array for which `arr[-1][j]=0;` is legal code. Now you might be doing something strange, so I can't say for sure that code is an error, but I reckon I'm about 99% confident.

Comment: @john thanks mate for helping me i will try to write diffrent logic. but why cant we assign value as arr[-1][j]=0;

Comment: @Evilport It's the rules of C++. If an array has size `n`, then the only legal accesses are from `0` to `n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing outside of the bounds of your array. If an array has size `n` then you cannot access `arr[n+1]` (or `arr[n]` either) and you cannot access `arr[-1]`. The only legal accesses are `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, ..., `arr[n-2]`, `arr[n-1]`.

That is why you are getting random values,